# An error occurrend while adding files to archive

Tags: backup, kubuntu, apache2, compression

I am trying to compress and backup my `/var/www/`. I stopped apache, but I still get this error:

```
An error occurrend while adding files to archive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have read rights to the entire directory or use sudo.

One thing you could do is this....

```
sudo -s
```

Then do:

```
tar -zcvf  /home/yourusername/var_www.tar.gz /var/www
```

I don't want to assume too much or give you too many options; so try this first and reply with any errors or success.  =)